# File sync from source to target nas path in linux not working as expected

Tags: linux, shell, file, copy, nas

We don't have rsync or xcopy available on linux machine, below is the suggested solution we have,is there any better way to implement file sync from source to target

alternate suggestion will be helpful

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check for correct number of arguments
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <source_directory> <user@remote:target_directory>"
    exit 1
fi

# Define the source and target directories from script arguments
SOURCE_DIR="$1"
TARGET_DIR="$2"

# Create a temporary directory for the file lists
TEMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d)

# Create a list of files and directories in the source directory
find "$SOURCE_DIR" -type f > "$TEMP_DIR/source_files.txt"
find "$SOURCE_DIR" -type d > "$TEMP_DIR/source_dirs.txt"

# Create a list of files and directories in the target directory
ssh "${TARGET_DIR%%:*}" "find '${TARGET_DIR##*:}' -type f" > "$TEMP_DIR/target_files.txt"
ssh "${TARGET_DIR%%:*}" "find '${TARGET_DIR##*:}' -type d" > "$TEMP_DIR/target_dirs.txt"

# Sync directories
while IFS= read -r dir
do
    relative_dir="${dir#$SOURCE_DIR}"
    if ! grep -qF "$relative_dir" "$TEMP_DIR/target_dirs.txt"; then
        ssh "${TARGET_DIR%%:*}" "mkdir -p '${TARGET_DIR##*:}$relative_dir'"
    fi
done < "$TEMP_DIR/source_dirs.txt"

# Sync files
while IFS= read -r file
do
    relative_file="${file#$SOURCE_DIR}"
    if ! grep -qF "$relative_file" "$TEMP_DIR/target_files.txt"; then
        scp "$file" "${TARGET_DIR}$relative_file"
    else
        source_info=$(stat -c "%Y %s" "$file")
        target_info=$(ssh "${TARGET_DIR%%:*}" "stat -c '%Y %s' '${TARGET_DIR##*:}$relative_file'")

        if [[ $source_info != $target_info ]]; then
            scp "$file" "${TARGET_DIR}$relative_file"
        fi
    fi
done < "$TEMP_DIR/source_files.txt"

# Clean up
rm -rf "$TEMP_DIR"
```

tried multiple custom scripts

Comment: cross-compile rsync and upload it to your nas? mount the nas filesystem on the src machine (nfs, sshfs, samba, etc) and run rsync there?